# Could an airliner pilot successfully exit alone from a controlled ocean ditching?

Tags: landing, emergency, emergency-procedures, oceanic, hijack

MH370's 777 disappeared into the Indian Ocean, the investigation positing a possibility of a pilot self-hijacking the plane and flying until resource exhaustion, then gliding into a "controlled" ocean crash; perhaps why so few pieces of wreckage have ever been found.

**Theoretically**, if a pilot in this scenario had wanted to be picked up safely (intact), would it be *technically* feasible, e.g., would a pilot be able to safely exit an airliner like this alone in the water by him/herself, etc.?

Note: I'm not suggesting this occurred, nor do I think such. Merely wondering if this would be mechanically/operationally possible, as I've imagined this understandably being an involved and time sensitive process that was perhaps never designed to be done by one person alone.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_landing#Passenger_airplane_water_ditchings  for more examples of "ditching" (=controlled water crash).

Comment: I think you are confusing safely with successfully. Ditching is inherently unsafe.

Comment: Even in ideal conditions, a planned, controlled ditch of a 777 in the Indian Ocean is not likely to be successful.  The chance of hitting a wave, or just impacting the water at the less-than-perfect angle and having the entire plane break up catastrophically is very high.   If you're suggesting this was part of a DB Cooper-style plan to survive the ditching and sail away like James Bond, then it was a very stupid plan.

Comment: "*the investigation positing a possibility of a pilot self-hijacking*" it would be good to remove this statement or to link to the paragraph which proves it, to me it's inexact. The report didn't find any mental health problem for the crew members. The only substantial findings are the ALERFA failure and the known part of the flight path couldn't be flown by the autopilot alone, but the flight path diversion reason is unknown. [Source](https://www.mot.gov.my/en/Laporan%20MH%20370/MH%20370%20Safety%20Investigation%20Report%20Slides.pdf). I rarely downvote questions, but I do for this one.

Comment: Perhaps it would be reasonable to ask whether the pilot could exit the aircraft after a successful ditching, without a significant number of passengers also exiting, and deploying life rafts &c.  And don't those rafts carry location beacons?

Comment: @mins Your source isn't the report, it's a slideshow "media briefing" of the report, and left out pertinent data from the report(s), namely, weeks before MH370 final, the PIC ran a flight sim on his home simulator: a 777 leaving KUL, flying NW into Strait of Malacca, veering left and down into south Indian Ocean, flying past fuel exhaustion, ending shortly after a user input of alt. 4,000ft. [MH370 ATSB Report, p98,99, overlayed routes/Arc7](https://imgur.com/a/ICVpCep) The simulator data for this flight had been wiped from PIC's computer, but was forensically recovered by the FBI.

Comment: @mins The investigation deemed the implications of this credibly and impactfully enough that it factored into MH370's search area in the Indian Ocean.

[AUS MH370 ATSB Report, p98-99](https://www.atsb.gov.au/);
MYS MH370 Investigation Report sec. 1.5.3_2, p27-28 (source link unreachable now);

Lastly, AUS PM Tony Abbott: [paraphrased] "[It was understood at the highest levels amongst high-ranking Malaysian government and top-level officials a belief that the veteran PIC deliberately downed the jet.]" 
[Associated Press](https://apnews.com/article/3feb92bc2b2105c4bce97d06316e9e8c)

Comment: @abelenky Thanks, useful to know. I wasn't suggesting that. Just wondering the feasibility of something like this even being mechanically/operationally possible.

Comment: What I see is you're not yet able to sustain your statement by a document. The document I linked is from the investigation agency and as a value. What you do is citing a government member who lacks knowledge in investigation, this is unfair, particularly since this declaration was contradicted [in the same article](https://apnews.com/article/3feb92bc2b2105c4bce97d06316e9e8c): "*In response, Malaysia’s former prime minister and police chief said there was no conclusive proof of pilot suicide*" a detail you're ignoring deliberately. I'm sad to see such methods have found a way to here.

Comment: @mins Did you not read my comments? I linked to the ATSB report which states this re: the PIC's home simulator, even stating that this data was enough that it factored into determing the search areas of ocean floor to scan for MH370. You linked to a media briefing. I linked to an official gov MH370 investigation report. I tried linking Malaysia's too, but they've apparently taken it down from their MOT site. Of course there's no "conclusive proof" -- there's no conclusive proof about anything at this point beyond MH370 went missing --  nor did I ever state such.

Answer (score 2):

> would a pilot be able to safely exit an airliner like this alone in the water by him/herself

Assuming there had been no breakup and the pilot just want to exit the cockpit without ever entering the cabin then yes, the 777 includes an emergency cockpit exit rope (with accompanying exit hatch) as shown in this video:

Comment: Not sure why you need the rope (water is relatively soft at that height) , the bigger point is that the window is openable and can be used for egress.

Comment: @RonBeyer yes, that was sort of implied but I made it more explicit

Comment: Because the rope's in the video, @RonBeyer, and this particular plane is on the ground. ;)

Comment: …getting from the cockpit to the middle of the ocean is where the hard part begins.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. Didn't even know this was a vector of possibility. I was picturing a time sensitive and potentially involved scenario that perhaps was never designed to be completable by one person alone.

Comment: @Coldblackice I suspect you'll find any emergency exit on any aircraft must be operable by a single person for somewhat obvious reasons

Comment: @Jamiec On the ground, sure. But in open ocean with not just an element of rising water, but complicated by a rolling sea state + inward water pressure perhaps preventing doors being opened (e.g. might a sequence be necessary to relieve pressure?), a potentially inoperable cockpit door, along with being unversed in piloting and all that would be involved, I wasn't sure. I had also heard at some point about Captain Scully in the Hudson operating something from the cockpit while passenger egress was in process.

Comment: Scully investigated aliens, Sully landed on the hudson ;)

Comment: @Jamiec LOL. I'll leave it, well played.